# Show element if id correspond

Tags: javascript, html

So, i have the following situation.
As the image below show, i have a table on the left which each row is associated with another whole table. On the right side i'm trying only to show the table related to the clicked row.
  [image: asdasdasdasd]

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/wallysoncarvalho/pen/xBryag?editors=1010) with what i got ultil now (in vanilla javascript), but is not woking and i dont think this is the best solution.

Javascript:

```
function funcao(idd){
  let id = parseInt(idd)
  let filhas = document.getElementById("info").
                querySelectorAll(".filha")

  for(var i = 0; i < filhas.length; i++){
    if(i === id){
      console.log("block");
      filhas[id].style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
      console.log("none");
      filhas[id].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="root">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Numero</th>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="funcao(0)">
      <td>wally</td>
      <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="funcao(1)">  
      <td>nada</td>
      <td>321</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id='info'>
    <table  class='filha' id='0' style='width: 100%;'>
    <tr>
      <th>Idade</th>
      <th>CPF</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>45644654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>121321321</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <table class='filha' id='1' style='width: 100%;'>
    <tr>
      <th>Idade</th>
      <th>CPF</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>45644654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>121321321</td>
    </tr>
  </table>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is OK, you have just a bug in the `funcao` function: you should change the style of `filhas[i]` rather than `filhas[id]`. Namely:

```
function funcao(idd){
  let id = parseInt(idd)
  let filhas = document.getElementById("info").
                querySelectorAll(".filha")

  for(var i = 0; i < filhas.length; i++){
    if(i === id){
      console.log("block");
      filhas[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
      console.log("none");
      filhas[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

I tested on your codepen, it seems to work.

To avoid the loop, you can use the Array interface; I strongly suggest to get familiar to it.
In this case a little extra care is needed, since the method `querySelectorAll` does not return an Array, but a NodeList which is a different, though similar, kind of object. Cfr. https://gomakethings.com/converting-a-nodelist-to-an-array-with-vanilla-javascript/.
Fortunately, the `Array.from` method allow to easily obtain an Array out of the NodeList.

We have:

```
function funcao(idd) {
    let id = parseInt(idd)
    let filhas = document.getElementById("info").
        querySelectorAll(".filha")
    const filhaAtual = Array.from(filhas).find(filha => filha.style.display === "block")
    if (filhaAtual) filhaAtual.style.display = "none"
    filhas[id].style.display = "block";
}
```

The `find` method in Array allows to obtain the first element satisfying a condition. If no element satisfies the condition, it returns `undefined`.
Hence the new version obtain the previously shown row using `find`, if there was indeed a shown row hides it, and finally shows the `id`-indexed row.

Hope it helps - Carlos

Comment: lol, such a stupid mistake. please unsdertand that i make this late at night :(.
Back to the code, i didint want to use loop to do this. Isn't there any way to get the child that have `filhas[i].style.display = "block" ` , set it to "none", and then get the other child with ** id = #idd ** and set this one **display = "block"** ?
Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: I add a way to do what you ask to the original answer.